# Wrap text around ad in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

```
<div id="537267840_INSERT_SLOT_ID_HERE" style="width:300px;height:250px;margin:0;padding:0">
  <noscript><iframe id="7226f0426f" name="7226f0426f" src="//oncampusweb-d.openx.net/w/1.0/afr?auid=537267840&cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="300" height="250" style="float: left; clear: left"><a href="//oncampusweb-d.openx.net/w/1.0/rc?cs=7226f0426f&cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE" ><img src="//oncampusweb-d.openx.net/w/1.0/ai?auid=537267840&cs=7226f0426f&cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE" border="0" alt="" style="float: left; clear: left"></a></iframe></noscript>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var OX_ads = OX_ads || [];
  OX_ads.push({
     slot_id: "537267840_INSERT_SLOT_ID_HERE",
     auid: "537267840"
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//oncampusweb-d.openx.net/w/1.0/jstag"></script>
 <p> Hello </p>
```

My problem is i want the code around this ad to be wrapping around the ad. Right now, the ad takes up the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this by saying that I'm not a CSS expert.  Someone might be able to provide a better answer.

The main problem seems to be that the iframe of the add doesn't exist on the page ahead of time, it is created by the Javascript snippet.  So you can't be *guaranteed* to know what exactly will be created, or where it will be created.  I'm going to assume for the purpose of this answer that the 3rd-party service will always create an iframe with an `id` attribute that starts with "ox_" (as it does now).  Based on that, you can just add this CSS:

```
iframe[id^='ox_'] {
  float:left;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2fo4qnzc/12/)